# Regular expression incremental parsing

Tags: regex, perl, unix, stream, terminal

Are there languages or tools that support the parsing of regexes on a character-by-character basis?

I think this may be equivalent to "regexes on streams" which is something that seems to be one of the features of the upcoming Perl version 6.

Basically I want to do this because I'm building a tool that does translation of a terminal stream over a pseudo-terminal, and it occurred to me that the ultimate sort of flexibility that should be attainable is by allowing the specification of regex-replace expressions.

The use case is that I want to allow my mouse scroll events to be passed to a naive program such as the `less` pager, which means my tool (which spawns `less` over a PTY) will be doing something like issuing the code `\x1b[?1000h` which switches on mouse reporting, and then subsequently translating every mouse wheel escape code received thereafter such as `\x1b[M!!` (the last several chars encode the mouse position within the terminal and should be ignored but also stripped) into the `\x1b[A` Up-arrow code.

As you can see being able to specify a regex that works on the stdin terminal-reading stream to generate the translated stream to send to the slave pty would be ideal.

Do I need to wait for Perl 6 to be able to achieve this? There must be particular reasons for why regex engines generally require having the whole string available?

It's pretty obvious I don't need the full blown power of regex here. I can speculate for instance that it might be the case that supporting backtracking makes stream-parsing regex impossible.

So since I don't need backtracking maybe there is some sort of light-weight regex engine out there that provides a stream API. It just seems like taking advantage of some form of parsing system (if one exists that is suitable) would be smarter than building something arbitrary.

Comment: I think you're looking for a finite-state-machine, not a stream regex handler.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed ?

Comment: So perhaps I can use sed by manually assembling the stream to it? Sounds like a plan. Sed becomes more powerful the more you use it.

Comment: an FSM (DFA) may be one way to represent it but it's clearly not as straightforward as a regular expression replacement operation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [s2p](http://perldoc.perl.org/s2p.html) is an example of something that I can use.

In particular, the potential of being able to set `$|` to not do line-buffering.

Actually I don't think this will work. It seems to be built around lines and uses the `s` operator to run regex.